# Windows 8 - Exit Java Application/Process without staying in background

Tags: java, windows-8, process, application-restart

I have an Java application that is started via a batch-script to set environment variables etc.

All works fine with Win7, but on Windows 8 the process doesn't stop completely and stays in background as I can see the javaw-process in the taskmanager. Then when starting the application again a second javaw-process starts.

I need the application to stop completely. Is there a way to do this in the application's shutdown procedure in Java code or are there settings in Win 8 to prevent this behaviour for Java? Or exists a commandline argument to pass when starting a process/java?

---

For clarification: There seems to be a new Windows 8 feature, that on close of an application the processes are just halted and the process will re-awake when the app is called again. But my legacy application does not support such re-awaking so I want to completely close the application and cleanly re-start it on the next call. For closing I currently call System.exit(), but regretably that's not enough and the process is in a state where it is neither dead nor alive but in a "sleeping mode".

Comment: Is there a difference between the JRE versions you are using on Win7  and Win8 ?

Comment: No I use the same one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest debugging the application on the Windows 8 system and look at what is happening in the code where you expect the application to shut down. It might be waiting on a specific resource.
If needed you can always execute [System.exit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) to force a shut down.

Comment: For clarification. This seems to be a new Win8 feature that on close of application the processes are just halted and rewakes them when the app is called again. But my legacy applications dies not support such re-awaking so i want to completely close the application. Therefore of course I call System.exit but this is not enough because THW Prozess is still alive